# Program runs slower when launched outside of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

I'm noticing some strange behaviour regarding my program. I'm writing it in C++ using Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 1 and it consists of an exe application that links against multiple DLLs and calls functions that are defined in those DLLs.

In my main program (which consists of several thousands of lines of code) I call a DLL function (let's call it `DLLFunction()` ) and I calculate the time taken by that call, like this:

```
auto beginTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

DllFunction();

auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

long long totalTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endTime - startTime).count();
```

What I am noticing is that it takes a much longer time when launching it outside Visual Studio. For example:

Running it in **debug** within Visual Studio with debugger attached --> `~50 ms`

Running it in **release** within Visual Studio **with debugger attached** ---> `~25 ms`

Running it in **release** within Visual Studio **without debugger attached** ---> `~20 ms`

Running it **outside** of Visual Studio (**release** build) ---> `~80 ms`

As you can see running it in release outside of Visual Studio actually takes longer than running a debug build with a debugger attached!

The offending DLL is built within the same solution by the same compiler, and I've double checked that all DLLs in the directory from where I launch my application are the right ones.

What could be the reason of such a behaviour?

**EDIT 5**:
The main application spawns another console application and communicates with it using named pipes. It turned out that not spawning that another application makes the DLL call fast outside Visual Studio.

However the same application is spawned both inside and outside Visual Studio, so i don't see why it slows down other calls just outside Visual Studio.

**EDIT 4**:
It turned out that this slow behaviour appears only if i place the function call in some part of the code of my main program, so it must be a problem related to that. It's many lines, but i'll continue researching.

Thank you for suggestions anyway, they were useful to identificate the problem.

**EDIT 3**:
Measurements with QueryPerfomanceCounter:

The CPU cycles measured inside Visual Studio (~50k) are half of those outside (~110k) (are those returned by QueryPerfomanceCounter() actual CPU cycles by the way?).

Dividing it by the frequency shows similar results to the std::chrono ones.

**EDIT 2**:
I checked with process explorer as suggested, the DLLs loaded within VS and outside VS are identical.

**EDIT 1**: as requested, i tried this:

```
auto beginTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    DllFunction();
}
auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

long long totalTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endTime - startTime).count();
```

And the results:
Running it in **release** within Visual Studio **with debugger attached** ---> `~19 seconds`

Running it **outside** of Visual Studio (**release** build) ---> `~40 seconds`

Comment: Timing a single function call is the wrong way to performance test your code. You need to call it many times in order to remove the effects of all sorts of things that could skew your results (thread scheduling, context switching, whatever.)

Comment: Woudln't timing be off even within Visual Studio? Anyway i tried calling the function in a loop and still there's a big difference between within and outside Visual Studio.

Comment: @Banex what's the difference then?

Comment: It wouldn't be off in a predictable manner, that's the important part.  Show us your new code and timings.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Running it 1000 times, within Visual Studio --> ~19seconds; outside Visual Studio --> ~40 seconds

Comment: Possibly to do with loading the DLL ... within VS, once it's been loded, it may stay loaded so can be accessed quicker.  Perhaps try running the release-build EXE outside of VS but while VS is still running (having run it from within VS).

Comment: @TripeHound Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly it didn't make a difference

Comment: Run process explorer and check which all Dll's are being loaded when run outside VS against within

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar Did a snapshot of the two processes, and they're running the same DLLs (same name, same path).

Comment: My guess is that it's cache related, the DLLs are loaded at different addresses and there's some conflict that keeps the cache swapping between two DLLs.

Comment: Try upping the thread priority of the executable? I'm guessing that this is some computation-intensive task, wouldn't surprise me if VS boosts priority of everything it is doing to make itself look good

Comment: Did you check if 'Run as administrator' option is different? i.e. if Visual Studio is launched in 'Run as Admin' mode but when you launch program outside its not in 'Run as Admin' mode or vice-versa?

Comment: You can check the CPU cycles instead of time ?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @NiteshChordiya Running as administrator didn't make a difference. I'll check the CPU cycles.

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar See the third edit

Comment: The working directory may be different when run from VS or from outside. Can you check if this is the case? Maybe `DLLFunction()` does something with files...

Comment: @rodrigo Actually DLLFunction() loads an image file. However the file (it's only one) is the same in both cases.

Comment: You can try using [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), filter the capture to your program name, and compare both cases. It is hard work, but very useful.

Comment: That image you load, is it literally the same file, or two byte-identical files? Because even if the files are identical, one may be read faster than the other, particularly if they are big.

Comment: @rodrigo They are two byte-identical files, but they're not that big (155 kilobytes).

Comment: @Banex: If they are two separated files, then they are likely two separated directory. Please try to run both programs with the exact same directory and same files. Just to be sure.

Comment: This is really a shot in the dark - I don't even use Windows :) Could it be that the search paths for the DLL are way different under VS than outside? I can imagine that inside VS there is a project directory which retains paths. Outside, the system path rules.

Comment: I edited and put the fourth edit on top, it turned out to be a problem with my main code. Still not sure what exactly is causing it.

Answer (score 4):

The DLL isn't loaded in the program until you call it the first time. If that function is very small, the program could be spending the majority of it's time just loading the DLL.
Try changing to this:

```
DllFunction();
auto beginTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    DllFunction();
}
auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

long long totalTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endTime - startTime).count();
```

This way, the loading time isn't considered.

Answer (score 3):

The offending code isn't loaded until you run it the first time, at which point it fetched the dll and loaded it into memory. Since you were running in Visual Studio, it's likely eager loading everything as soon as you start the debugger, negating that first-call overhead. Doing this prevents the code from needing the extra space for the loaded DLL until it's absolutely sure it's needed, and can save space and time if certain references never get called.

When testing for access times such as this, you should ALWAYS put such tests through a loop and run them many many times, since conditions such as these severely affect the first call, but not subsequent calls, and other conditions of the system (such as resources demanded by another process) can cause fluctuations you'll want to flatten out for a good test. Never trust the time on a single-instance execution.

Answer (score 0):

I also would try by removing the code optimizations. May be some inline function behavior is giving more performance in VS debugger.

Try optimizations are off, right click on your project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Optimization -> Optimization = Disabled.