# Launching the program from Visual Studio debugger is faster than launching it from outside

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, release

Summary:

I saw that when I ran the program from Visual Studio (F5), a pair of multiplications took around:

x64: 3.8~ ms

Win32: 4.5~ ms

However when I ran it from outside they took:

x64: 6.59~ ms

Win32: 6.62~ ms

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

More info:

I wanted to test the matrix multiplication speed of glm library and iterating over a number of them with hash map, vector and array. (to calculate transformation matrices for rendering)

So, using QueryPerformanceCounter, I tested for 50000~ multiplication pairs for 1000 times to get an average timing. (default Visual Studio 2013 empty project Release configuration)

Normally one would expect the program to be faster when ran outside of Visual Studio, so I also tried it again with setting the program priority programmatically, which made no difference.

To give an idea an example loop looks like this:

```
    timer.start();
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsVector.size(); i++)
        {
            if (objectsVector[i]->mMeshRefID > 0)
            {
                results[i].worldTransformationMatrix = objectsVector[i]->getWorld();
                results[i].mMeshRefID = objectsVector[i]->mMeshRefID;
            }
        }
    }
    timer.getTimeDiff();
```

If anyone wanted to take a look at or try the full code link is here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xilydyvp3lublrk/matmult.zip

P.S: I also found this link, which I think is irrelevant because I have no DLLs:
[Program runs slower when launched outside of Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436245/program-runs-slower-when-launched-outside-of-visual-studio)

P.P.S: Two Windows 8 PCs gave the same results, while the timings were the same under a Windows 7 PC (ran a little slower (0.8~ms) from Visual Studio, which should be the case)

**More:** I replaced glm with my own code that represents matrices as a float array, while the timings are better, running from Visual Studio is still much faster. I still don't know how to achieve that speed from outside Visual Studio.

Comment: TL;DR. Check it once by disabling your antivirus.

Comment: I only have Windows Defender, and disabling it did not affect the timings

Comment: Are you talking about Release configuration in both scenarios?

Comment: Yes, both are Release

Comment: Are you running MSVC as admin?

Comment: Yes, I have UAC completely disabled so everything is run as admin